# Hide a text in a div tag that has no unique ID

Tags: jquery, html, css, hide

I need help hiding the "Silver=#" and "Manual=#" texts. These texts has no unique ID, so I have no idea on how can I hide these texts. Please help. You may check this specific page here --> https://www.colonialacres.com/product-p/wbs-g8-y.htm

[image]

Comment: Is there no way to edit the Volusion template?

Comment: I have access to its admin but there are a lots of items like this that has silver/manual text. I mean, I can close them inside a comment tag but I have to check each item manually that has this text. This is why I'm looking for a fast way to hide the text using css or some scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove them from DOM:

```
$('[itemprop="offers"]').contents().filter(function () {
  return this.nodeType == 3 && this.data.match(/Silver|Manual/); 
}).remove();
```

Or wrap them with span and hide:

```
$('[itemprop="offers"]').contents().filter(function () {
  return this.nodeType == 3 && this.data.match(/Silver|Manual/); 
}).each(function(i, el) {
  $(el).replaceWith($('<span>').text(el.data).css('display', 'none'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("SELECTOR:contains('STRING')").remove();
```

Where SELECTOR is equel to your div/element you want to select with the string you want to hide in (something like div table tbody tr td) and STRING is equel to the string you want to hide.

JSFiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/5tu7weby/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can try how you did with `<!` in the html or you can use a span element then add css `{ display:none;}`